# trying to set env var in jenkins star team plugin to use in build

Tags: plugins, jenkins, environment-variables, starteam

I am using the starteam plug-in in jenkins. In the plug-in I added code to get the some info associated with the version. now the problem is getting it back to jenkins as an env var or build var so it will be passed into my ant build.

I tried using build.getBuildVariables.put, build.getEnvVars.., build.getEnvironment(listener) and they don't appear to add the new vars at all.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: install [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), export your variables into a file, use the plugin in a build step to inject the variables from that file. By the way, you can examine the plugin code (the GitHub link is on the plugin page) to find out how they make it work.

Comment: Thanks. I will see how they add it to the env.